# How to upgrade legacy Entity Framework project?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'd like to upgrade my project to use Entity Framework v5+ so I can take advantage of newer features such as enum support, and also bring into line with another part of the system that already uses EF5.

The project is contained in a solution that has not been kept up to date for a number (4+) of years.  There are 2 EDMX files that define the databases that the application uses, and these generate model classes that inherit from EntityObject, plus ObjectContext based classes.  The project **doesn't** reference *EntityFramework.dll*, but does reference *System.Data.Entity* (v4.0.0.0, runtime version: v4.0.30319).  For reference the project targets .NET 4.5.1, and I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

At the moment I'm not sure how to upgrade what I have to EF5.  All the references I can find expect the project to already be referencing EntityFramework, which is not the case here.

So my question is:

- What steps do I need to take in order to upgrade my project to EF5?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm facing the same dilemma. What did you end up doing to resolve this? There's not much guidance on the web.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember!  I do know that the project uses Entity Framework via NuGet, so I suspect I removed System.Data.Entity and replaced it with the equivalent from NuGet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the following links can help you to add the EntityFramework to your project:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906#runtime

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/03/10/ef6-1-3-rtm-available.aspx

Otherwise it can be the case, that you missed to install Microsofts SQL Server Data Tools to your VS2015. This is necessary to see the edmx designer.

If thats true, you have to install it via Control Panel>Program & Features>VS2015>Change>Customize(? I see the german word there)>Windows- and Webdevelopment>Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools